# Is there emulator available for HTC Thunderbolt?

Tags: android, android-emulator, htc-thunderbolt

I have created an application its working fine on HTC Wildfire but one of my application user having HTC Thunderbolt has reported that it is generating Application Force Close dialog.
As i don't have real device and i want to sort out the issue, i want to know is there any emulator available for HTC Thunderbolt so that i can test my application on it?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware related bugs can't be tested with the emulator. So the answer is no, there is no such thing.

If the two phones have different Android versions and that is the source of the error then you can find the error with an emulator

Answer (score 0):

An emulator won't help much to fix a problem with a specific device.

First of all you should acquire a stacktrace from the user using the Android Market or an EMail intent.

After that you can try to reproduce the problem using a service like http://www.deviceanywhere.com/ for example.